# Prestashop 1.7.8.0 problem disable scroll up after changing the attributes

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a problem in Prestashop 1.7.8.0 I want to disable the scroll up after changing the attributes how to do it?
Moves the page up every time
I have core.js file combined and i dont know where to change this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found is to install prestashop with local environments and edit _dev folder inside theme. Go to inside folder: themes/classic/_dev/js/listing.js and remove window.scrollTo(0, 0); from:

```
prestashop.on('updateProductList', (data) => {
   updateProductListDOM(data);
   window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```